# Trying to tally number of failed attempts per login id in R

Tags: r

I am trying to tabulate from an audit log the number of failed attempts by login id. Suppose the audit log is as follows:

```
User ID   | LoginStatus  | LoginAttempt
----------+--------------+-----------------
2ABQM4    | F            | 1
2ABQM4    | F            | 2
1BIDU8    | F            | 1
1YUM8T    | F            | 1
2MP32A    | F            | 1
2MP32A    | F            | 2
2ABQM4    | F            | 3
1BIDU8    | F            | 2
```

I would like to create a table where the max login attempts is shown by User ID as follows:

```
User ID   | MaxLoginAttempt
----------+-----------------
2ABQM4    | 3
1BIDU8    | 2
1YUM8T    | 1
2MP32A    | 2
```

I am unsure of how to do it in R. Thanking gurus and seniors in advance for kind assistance.

Arifin

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `aggregate` :

```
aggregate(LoginStatus~User.ID,  df, function(x) sum(x == 'F'))

#  User.ID LoginStatus
#1  1BIDU8           2
#2  1YUM8T           1
#3  2ABQM4           3
#4  2MP32A           2
```

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(User.ID) %>% summarise(Failed_Attempt = sum(LoginStatus == 'F'))
```

and `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, sum(LoginStatus == 'F'), User.ID]
```

In the example, that you have shared all the `LoginStatus` is always `'F'` in which case you can count number of rows in each group as well.